# Getting count of files in folder via REST call

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint list that has tasks, and a document library where the associated files for those tasks are stored. When a task is ready to archive, I want to kick off a workflow that will automatically move the task documents into the documents archive library.

In my workflow, I'm calling a web service to get the documents in the folder so I can get a count of the documents for my loop that will iterate through them and move them. The URL I am calling is

```
{mySiteURL}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL('{MyLibraryRelativeURL}/1')/Files?$expand=folders,files
```

When I run this, the output I get is

```
<id>974ecc06-e49f-43b2-934c-9a9cb67e684b</id><title /><updated>2019-11-22T20:29:16Z</updated><author><name /></author></feed>
```

I'm not getting any expanded results or anything resembling the contents of the folder, just the folder itself. And yes, I have verified that there are two files inside the folder.

If it would be better, I do have a column (Tasker ID) that is on each file, that I could use to get the files with.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that I was in fact getting results, but that doing a *get d/results from JSONresults (output to dataset)* before counting the results was the problem. Changing the count from *Get d/results* to just going directly to the JSONresults from the REST call got me the response I was expecting.